# Slider with 2 Pointers in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, controls

I want to have a slider with pointers so the user can set one for the lower range and one for the higher range. Something similar to this:

https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

Is there a class in MFC or BCGSoft that can do that?

Comment: There's no common control in Win32 that has that feature or behavior. Hence, nothing in MFC that will do that.  You can always do your own custom control.

Comment: Maybe you can find here some control that will help you: https://www.codeproject.com/KB/progress/